# Duplicate classes error on Android RethinkDB implementation

Tags: java, android, rethinkdb

Im making an realtime messaging app. I added RethinkDB implementation to gradle and this error flashing:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: org.hamcrest.core.DescribedAs","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Program type already present: org.hamcrest.core.DescribedAs
```

I cant find which other implementation includes hamcrest.core.DescribedAs, so can you help me to find it or solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error with Android Studio Code Inspector tool. On the Inspector, i found incompatible(not matched classes of two different libraries) gradle versions. Change the gradle versions of this libraries' classes.